# Client-side Prism.js with npm

Tags: javascript, npm, prism.js

I'm trying to use **Prism.js** syntax highlighter client-side as an `npm` dependency, instead of loading it from `<script src="...">` tags. Here is the Prism reference in package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "prismjs": "^1.5.1"
    }
}
```

And the way I'm trying to use it in my code

```
import Prism from 'prismjs'
Prism.highlightAll();
```

This produces the following results:

- Tokenizing works for basic languages (html, javascript...)
- Tokenizing does not work for other specific languages (lua, handlebars...)
- For all languages, syntax coloring isn't applied (css file doesn't seem loaded)

So I'm wondering

- Are there other language-specific packages (like prismjs-handlebars for instance)?
- Are there theme-specific packages (like prism-okaidia for instance) which would import the css?

--

**TL;DR**

**How to load/use Prism.js client-side from `npm` instead of from script tags?**

Comment: npm as in remote repository, so that you won't have to download the file into your project?

Comment: @silicakes npm as in package manager for a Vue.js app (similar to React.js)

Comment: gotta say that I didn't get the question up until I read your answer, you basically wanted to compile imported statements into your source using webpack. Got me quite confused[:

Comment: @silicakes sorry about that, by the time I wrote the question I was very confused too, hence the lack of clarity despite the simple thing I actually wanted to do

Comment: All's good, glad you found your answer!

Answer (score 17):

I eventually found the way to do this.

**1. Add `style-loader` and `css-loader` to package.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
        "prismjs": "^1.5.1"
    }
}
```

**2. Load css files in `webpack.config.js`**

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

**3. Import desired files in the application**

```
import Prism from 'prismjs'
import 'prismjs/themes/prism-okaidia.css'
import 'prismjs/components/prism-handlebars.min.js'
import 'prismjs/components/prism-lua.min.js'

Prism.highlightAll();
```

Comment: ughhh only this worked for me `import 'prismjs';`, then Prism was a global, I tried a couple other ways, didn't work, super annoys...I don't see anywhere in their docs that mentions importing code Webpack-style..

Comment: @AlexanderMills, it may be a little late, but if you add ```  new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
    new RegExp("^prism-\w+$")
    , "prism-xml"
  )``` to your plugins, you can only import the language you need.